# A question regarding quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematics

If quantum mechanics does not follow the phenomena of classic physics, then shouldn't we consider the possibility that conventional mathematical language might not be sufficient enough? Shouldn't quantum mathematics be different from conventional mathematics? I mean given the fact that quantum mechanics is absurd as it is, shouldn't this be given some consideration too?

Comment: Definition of what is conventional mathematics is highly subjective. The whole question in its present form seems to foster opinion-based answers. I suggest you try to formulate better your question.

Comment: The mathematical structure of quantum mechanics isn't anything special, from a mathematical perspective. A mathematician would not recognise quantum mechanics and classical mechanics as inherently different, merely an application of two different areas of mathematics. There's no reason to believe we'll reach a point at which experimental evidence will become entirely incompatible with anything we can find in maths.

Comment: There is absolutely on such thing as "conventional" and "nonconventional" math. We invent new aspects of math when we need them to help describe the natural world as we observe it.

Comment: Quantum mechanics is no more absurd than the reality it describes.

Answer (score 5):

We do have special mathematical language for Quantum mechanics - wave functions, operators, matrices, path integrals, etc. It was quite new at the time, but by now everyone is used to it, and it became the stuff for the undergraduate math courses that one takes before studying QM.

Also Heisenberg was unaware of matrix algebra (or didn't think of it) and reinvented matrices from scratch for his formulation of the QM. [It was Max Born who told him that it was not new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_entryway_to_matrix_mechanics#Development_of_full_quantum_mechanical_theory):

```
After Heisenberg wrote his ground breaking paper, he turned it over to one of his 
senior colleagues for any needed corrections and went on a well-deserved vacation. 
Max Born puzzled over the equations and the non-commuting equations that Heisenberg 
had found troublesome and disturbing. After several days he realized that these 
equations amounted to directions for writing out matrices. Matrices were a bit off 
the beaten track, even for mathematicians of that time, but how to do math with them 
was already clearly established. He and a few colleagues took up the task of 
working everything out in matrix form before Heisenberg returned from his time off, 
and within a few months the new quantum mechanics in matrix form formed the basis 
for another paper.
```

Comment: *It was Bohr ...* Actually it was Born. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_entryway_to_matrix_mechanics).

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Fixed.

Comment: It still says “It was Bohr…”.

Comment: @G.Smith indeed. Now it should be better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum mechanics is a theory which describes (very well) the behavior of atomic-size systems, using mathematics which, even though different from the mathematics used to describe classical mechanics, is very standard and well studied.

There is no need to depart from this well understood framework to describe quantum mechanics.

The need to explore other possibilities and sometimes open new branches of mathematics only arises when quantum mechanics (and its relativistic extension Quantum Field Theory) is not enough to accurately predict experimental data or incapable of making predictions. This is the case when trying to find theories of quantum gravity and more generally beyond-standard-model theories, where the key might be some new mathematical theory that is yet to be invented.

However, if by "conventional mathematical language" you mean the usual rules of logic and deduction, I feel like the consensus is that mathematics founded on the usual ones are powerful enough so that we can hope to find the solution to our problems within this paradigm. I don't know of any attempt to develop our knowledge of  theoretical physics based on unconventional logic systems.